# Upside down text in browsers and applications

Tags: html

Check out the answer to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/384423) question. How did the inverted text appear as text? In other words, I was expecting it to be an image.

Comment: Why don't you ask on that question, or if you have a new question come up with a much better headline.

Comment: Why ask _here_? Entirely off-topic.

Comment: maybe you should have just googled "upside down text" and you would have got your answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Carefully chosen Unicode Characters, notice that the bases don't align properly

uɐɥʞ lǝǝɥɐɹ ollǝH

http://www.upsidedowntext.com/

Comment: Thanks. That seems like the best approach since it is standard agnostic and will run on any browser that supports unicode.

Comment: try to use this .txtUpsideDown { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2); /* IE6,IE7 / ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)"; / IE8 / -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg); / FF3.5+ / -o-transform: rotate(-180deg); / Opera 10.5 / -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); / Safari 3.1+, Chrome */ position: absolute; }

Answer (score 2):

˙ʇuıodpuɐʇs ןɐɔıuɥɔǝʇ ɐ ɯoɹɟ ǝuop ʎןןɐnʇɔɐ sı sıɥʇ ʍoɥ ǝɹns ʇou ˙˙˙pǝsnɯɐ ɯ,ı

http://www.fliptext.org/